# Spring Integration DSL routing based on message header in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

My message contains String and I want route messages based on header, likes bellow:

```
            .route<Message<String?>, String> {
                when (it.headers["routing_header"] as Int) {
                    1 -> "channel_1"
                    2 -> "channel_2"
                    else -> "nullChannel"
                }
            }
```

In this case I have error in cast String

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.springframework.messaging.Message

What is wrong in my routing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to look into dedicated Spring Integration Kotlin DSL: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/kotlin-dsl.html

That `route` could be configured like this:

```
                route<Message<String?>> {
                    when (it.headers["routing_header"] as Int?) {
                        1 -> "channel_1"
                        2 -> "channel_2"
                        else -> "nullChannel"
                    }
                }
```

Pay attention to the fix for `Int?` since your header might be missed and will be returned as `null`.

If you are still suck with combination of Java DSL in Kotlin, then probably the fix is like this:

```
                        .route(Message::class.java) {
                            when (it.headers["routing_header"] as Int?) {
                                1 -> "channel_1"
                                2 -> "channel_2"
                                else -> "nullChannel"
                            }
                        }
```

Java does generics erasure, so we don't know that `Message` type expectation at runtime. Therefore Java variant wants from us that type explicitly, while Kotlin one does reified typing.

Comment: route(Message::class.java) works well, thx Artem